# Apache Spark CSV not parsing header row with option("headers", true) included

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I see several questions related to this, but the solutions are all to use the headers, true option.  However, I have a very basic csv file that I can demonstrate that this isn't working on. I'm using Spark 2.4.0 (started on 2.3, but upgraded to see if there were any old bugs).

```
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().option("headers", true)
        .format("csv")
        .load("src/main/resources/students.csv");
```

//csv file:

```
studentId,studentName,State,GPA,favoritBookTitle,working
1100,Royce Piche,NJ,1.5,To Kill a Mockingbird,TRUE
1120,Alexis Morriss,NJ,3.0,Pride and Prejudice,FALSE
```

//output

```
+---------+--------------+-----+---+--------------------+-------+
|      _c0|           _c1|  _c2|_c3|                 _c4|    _c5|
+---------+--------------+-----+---+--------------------+-------+
|studentid|   studentname|State|GPA|    favoritbooktitle|working|
|     1100|   Royce Piche|   NJ|1.5|To Kill a Mocking...|   TRUE|
|     1120|Alexis Morriss|   NJ|3.0| Pride and Prejudice|  FALSE|
```

I've tried a number of different ways to read the csv and or force the headers, including invoking the csv mehtod vs loading. The javadocs and other info indicate that this should work. Am I missing or overlooking something?  Or is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Typo - [the option is `header` not `headers`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/13650fc58e1fcf2cf2a26ba11c819185ae1acc1f/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L366).

Comment: :facepalm:  Thank you!